# Dynamically-populated <select> not populated during testing with Codeception

Tags: html, forms, dom, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I am relatively new to Codeception and am trying to perform acceptance testing of a form using it and Selenium WebDriver with Firefox. The form (available at http://www.brighton-hove.gov.uk/content/parking-and-travel/parking/find-your-parking-zone ) consists primarily of a text box and an auto-populated  which is inserted into the DOM in the event that the input into the text box results in multiple matches; each field also has a submit button.

The issue I am experiencing is that, when tested normally in Firefox the  behaves as expected and is auto-populated in cases where the initial, textual search returns multiple matches (for example, entering any Brighton postcode, although the particular scenario is to search for 'Brighton Town Hall, Bartholomew Square', which returns 3 results). However, when attempting to test via Codeception (either running a complete test or attempting each step via the console), the  gets inserted into the DOM but never appears to be populated with real results (the only  element it contains being 'Please select your address...').

My test steps are as follows:

```
$I->amOnUrl('http://www.brighton-hove.gov.uk/content/parking-and-travel/parking/find-your-parking-zone');
$I->fillField('Enter your postcode or house number and street','Brighton Town Hall, Bartholomew Square');

// XPath is used here as the form elements' 'id's, 'class'es and 'name's are auto-generated (the one above just happens to have a label).
$I->click("//div[@id='achieveform']/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/input[@type='submit' and @value='Search'])";

// I've also tried using 'submitForm(...)' here, rather than just clicking the button.

// Wait an unnecessarily long amount of time in the hope that the dropdown appears and is also populated...
$I->waitForElement("//div[@id='achieveform']/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/span/select", 5);

// The first option is there...
$I->seeElementInDOM("//div[@id='achieveform']/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/span/select/option[1]");

// ...but it doesn't have 4 options, as expected.
$I->seeNumberOfElements("//div[@id='achieveform']/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/span/select/option", 4);
```

Although the test I am looking to perform is essentially black-box my next course of action is to attempt to look into tracing the form submissions and DOM updates, even though that level of knowledge of the underlying structure of the system should not be necessary. Am I overlooking something simple? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, it turns out it wasn't anything to do with Codecepetion after all: the issue was partly to do with the backend logic behind the search form (which doesn't seem to like the comma) and partly due to me for not noticing that the behaviour with the empty dropdown did actually also occur when performing the same actions outside of Codeception.

Moderators: this thread can be closed/removed (as the issue was a non-issue within the context of Codeception) now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not filling value in the right field or the text input field of the search box:

**instead of:**

```
$I->fillField('Enter your postcode or house number and street','Brighton Town Hall, Bartholomew Square');
```

**Use:**

```
$I->fillField('.dataelr input', "Your Value here");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Anirudh,

Thanks for your reply.

As far as I can see, the fact that the dropdown appears means that there is valid, though ambiguous, input into the text box.

Additionally, even if the issue were to do with the referencing of the text box, the comments in the code state

`the form elements' 'id's, 'class'es and 'name's are auto-generated ([the field you're referencing] just happens to have a label [making it easier to reference])`

As such, referencing a particular field by CSS ID is non-reproduceable.

Comment: Well I updated the answer to use stable css reference which doesnt use Is, but I don't understand why you are trying to fill a value in the label, only textbox or fields with <input> tag can be used.

Comment: From http://codeception.com/docs/04-AcceptanceTests (the 'Forms' section; it doesn't seem to have an anchor), I was under the impression that it is possible to have form elements as follows:

`<label for="foo">Bar</label>
<input name="foo" ... />`

Then, in Codeception:

`$I->fillField('Bar','CONTENT');`

For completeness I tried your suggestion of using a stable CSS reference, with expected results. To reiterate, the referencing of the text field is not the issue as the field was being filled correctly by the code snippet I posted.

Comment: To clarify, what I'm actually asking is, given that the <select> element and its contents seem to be returned via AJAX following the submission of the contents of the text field, why simply waiting far longer than necessary for the <select> to appear/become populated isn't enough.

I've also looked briefly into using something along the lines of 
`waitForJS("return $.active == 0;", 10);` without it seeming to have any effect.